# Create multiple buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom, button

I have checked for syntax errors and it does seems like everything is okay, it just does not do anything when loading the body of the page. I know I have linked the script correctly to the html file, because I've already implemented a JS Clock which displays itself in the page as you can see in the pen. Is there anything wrong with my code? Why aren't my 10 buttons displaying? I fear Bootstrap may be preventing me from getting my buttons show up.

My purpose is to create 10 buttons, so that I don't have to write the same code 10 times.

The Codepen is just to check out my code, I work on Atom usually.  [This is my Codepen!](https://codepen.io/Watcher16/pen/zjBWpB)

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="buttons">

</div>

function createButtons() { 
  for(i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-success\">Chapter[i]</button>");
    var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
  }
}
document.body.addEventListener("load", createButtons(), false);
```

Comment: That's not how you use [createElement, view documentation on how to use it correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#Syntax). You should have seen errors on the console due to it

Comment: Please (re)read the [documentation on `createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: `var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons"); for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { buttonDiv.innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Chapter['+i+']</button>'; }`

Answer (score 5):

The function `createElement` accept a tag name as argument.

```
var Chapter = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for(i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = Chapter[i];
    button.className = "btn btn-outline-success";
    var buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve your code and add dynamic functions

```
let buttonDiv = document.getElementById("buttons");

const createButtons = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = `${i}`;
    button.textContent = `Button #${i}`
    button.click(buttonEvent(i));
    buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
  }
}

const buttonEvent = i => {
  document.body.addEventListener( 'click',  (event)  => {
    if(event.target.id === i.toString()) alert(event.target.id);
    event.preventDefault();

  });
}



document.body.addEventListener("load", createButtons(), false);
```